# Cannot update the BIOS on a Zotac EN1070K

Tags: boot, usb, bios

**TL;DR:** I can't set USB as priority boot device, and thus cannot enter the Debug Mode necessary to update the BIOS from USB stick.

Long version:
I was kindly given a Zotac EN1070K second hand, ex-corporate. It was used to run sinage so there's just a very basic OS on there and to be honest I don't know what it is, but it isn't letting me access a menu or task manager or such. I want to format the disk before using it. My plan was to boot Linux Mint from USB and do it that way. However, I get an ACPI BIOS error when trying to boot from USB.

As such, I've tried to update the BIOS. I downloaded the official patch for this model from Zotac's website and the Readme says I have to set USB as the first priority boot device then to enter 'ME Debug Mode' and it'll boot to the UEFI Shell Command mode for flashing, however in the options for setting the boot priority, only the built in SSD is shown as an option (despite the USB stick already being plugged in).

I can boot from USB directly in the BIOS, but this doesn't work as Debug Mode isn't enabled in that case. I followed suggestions from this Reddit thread but it appears this guy's problem also isn't resolved: https://www.reddit.com/r/ZOTAC/comments/11eo2y0/how_on_earth_do_you_update_the_bios_on_a_zotac/

Any thoughts? I'm not experienced with this kind of thing, so please explain to me like I'm five years old if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Most OS installations give you the option of formatting the disk,
so BIOS update is not strictly required.

The article
[How to install an OS onto a ZBOX Mini PC](https://www.zotac.com/fr/faq/how-install-os-zbox-mini-pc) says :

> Insert bootable media into USB port boot the ZBOX Mini PC system and upon boot up press the F8 button on the keyboard to invoke the boot options. Select the corresponding boot media and install.

Ensure that the boot media matches the characteristics of the
computer, especially as regarding UEFI/BIOS.

Comment: As I wrote, I get an ACPI BIOS error when trying to boot Linux Mint from USB. That's why I want to update the BIOS.

Comment: What error message are you getting? Did you try to identify the installed OS?

Comment: It says: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.CUP0._CPC1, AE_NOT_FOUND] (20210730/psargs-330). I'm not sure how to identify the OS, as there is not much of a GUI to investigate, and I am not sure how to do it otherwise.

Comment: These errors [seem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416198/ubuntu-22-04-acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-errors-on-asus-x7) to be only warnings.

Comment: How do I get around it? I tried editing GRUB, putting noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll after quiet splash but it still got stuck at those warning messages, with no option to continue (enter doesn't work and I can't type anything at that point)

Comment: There are some workarounds [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416198/ubuntu-22-04-acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-errors-on-asus-x7). I don't know how well they will work for your case. The post also links to the [bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213023) for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that model has an SD slot on the front of it.  Maybe try putting a copy of this bios on an SD card and seeing if you can boot from that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).